# Linux server high memory usage without applications

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory, out-of-memory, meminfo

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.4 server with 32GB RAM.
The server is running a bunch of LXD containers and two VMs (libvirt+qemu+kvm).

After startup, with all services running, the RAM utilization is about ~12GB.

After 3-4 weeks the RAM utilization reaches ~90%.
If I stop all containers and VMs the utilization is still ~20GB.
However, I cannot figure out who is claiming this memory.
I have already tried clearing the cache, but that doesn't change much.
I compiled the kernel with support for *kmemleak* but it did not detect anything useful but shows up in slabtop.

systemd-cgtop:

```
/                                                                                          593      -    23.7G        -        -
machine.slice                                                                                -      -     1.4G        -        -
system.slice                                                                               116      -   301.1M        -        -
user.slice                                                                                  11      -   141.9M        -        -
user.slice/user-1000.slice                                                                  11      -   121.6M        -        -
system.slice/systemd-journald.service                                                        1      -    83.8M        -        -
user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-297429.scope                                              5      -    81.0M        -        -
system.slice/libvirtd.service                                                               22      -    46.2M        -        -
user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service                                                 6      -    39.8M        -        -
system.slice/snapd.service                                                                  36      -    19.8M        -        -
system.slice/cron.service                                                                    1      -    19.3M        -        -
init.scope                                                                                   1      -    14.0M        -        -
system.slice/systemd-udevd.service                                                           1      -    13.2M        -        -
system.slice/multipathd.service                                                              7      -    10.8M        -        -
system.slice/NetworkManager.service                                                          3      -     5.8M        -        -
system.slice/networkd-dispatcher.service                                                     1      -     5.4M        -        -
system.slice/ssh.service                                                                     1      -     5.0M        -        -
system.slice/ModemManager.service                                                            3      -     4.5M        -        -
system.slice/systemd-networkd.service                                                        1      -     3.5M        -        -
system.slice/accounts-daemon.service                                                         3      -     3.5M        -        -
system.slice/udisks2.service                                                                 5      -     3.4M        -        -
system.slice/polkit.service                                                                  3      -     3.0M        -        -
system.slice/rsyslog.service                                                                 4      -     2.8M        -        -
system.slice/systemd-resolved.service                                                        1      -     2.4M        -        -
system.slice/unattended-upgrades.service                                                     2      -     1.8M        -        -
system.slice/dbus.service                                                                    1      -     1.8M        -        -
system.slice/systemd-logind.service                                                          1      -     1.7M        -        -
system.slice/smartmontools.service                                                           1      -     1.5M        -        -
system.slice/systemd-machined.service                                                        1      -     1.5M        -        -
system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service                                                       2      -     1.4M        -        -
system.slice/virtlogd.service                                                                1      -     1.3M        -        -
system.slice/rtkit-daemon.service                                                            3      -     1.2M        -        -
```

/proc/meminfo:

```
MemTotal:       32718604 kB
MemFree:        11480728 kB
MemAvailable:   11612788 kB
Buffers:              28 kB
Cached:           144512 kB
SwapCached:       855404 kB
Active:           520504 kB
Inactive:         541588 kB
Active(anon):     441708 kB
Inactive(anon):   484240 kB
Active(file):      78796 kB
Inactive(file):    57348 kB
Unevictable:       18664 kB
Mlocked:           18664 kB
SwapTotal:      33043136 kB
SwapFree:       32031680 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         94680 kB
Mapped:           126592 kB
Shmem:               660 kB
KReclaimable:     432484 kB
Slab:           10784740 kB
SReclaimable:     432484 kB
SUnreclaim:     10352256 kB
KernelStack:       10512 kB
PageTables:         5052 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    49402436 kB
Committed_AS:    1816364 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      152512 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:          8868864 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:    19383100 kB
DirectMap2M:    14053376 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

slabtop:

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 30513607 / 33423869 (91.3%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 1384092 / 1384092 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 123 / 203 (60.6%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 9965969.20K / 10757454.91K (92.6%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.32K / 16.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
27156909 26001970  95%    0.30K 1194104       26   9552832K kmemleak_object        
754624 742232  98%    0.06K  11791       64     47164K kmalloc-64             
654675 278378  42%    0.57K  23382       28    374112K radix_tree_node        
593436 348958  58%    0.08K  11636       51     46544K Acpi-State             
559744 418325  74%    0.03K   4373      128     17492K kmalloc-32             
496320 483104  97%    0.12K  15510       32     62040K kernfs_node_cache      
487104 155952  32%    0.06K   7611       64     30444K vmap_area              
394240 165965  42%    0.14K  14080       28     56320K btrfs_extent_map       
355580 342674  96%    0.09K   7730       46     30920K trace_event_file       
339573 338310  99%    4.00K  42465        8   1358880K kmalloc-4k             
306348 154794  50%    0.19K   7410       42     59280K dentry                 
145931 104400  71%    1.13K  11552       28    369664K btrfs_inode            
137728 137174  99%    0.02K    538      256      2152K kmalloc-16             
112672  74034  65%    0.50K   3671       32     58736K kmalloc-512            
102479  62366  60%    0.30K   4093       26     32744K btrfs_delayed_node     
 68880  66890  97%    2.00K   4305       16    137760K kmalloc-2k             
 66656  48345  72%    0.25K   2083       32     16664K kmalloc-256            
 64110  47818  74%    0.59K   2376       27     38016K inode_cache            
 50176  50176 100%    0.01K     98      512       392K kmalloc-8              
 44710  43744  97%    0.02K    263      170      1052K lsm_file_cache         
 43056  11444  26%    0.25K   1418       32     11344K pool_workqueue         
 36480  29052  79%    0.06K    570       64      2280K kmalloc-rcl-64         
 33920  25846  76%    0.06K    530       64      2120K anon_vma_chain         
 24822  14264  57%    0.19K    832       42      6656K kmalloc-192            
 23552  23552 100%    0.03K    184      128       736K fsnotify_mark_connector
 23517  17994  76%    0.20K    603       39      4824K vm_area_struct         
 19572  14909  76%    0.09K    466       42      1864K kmalloc-rcl-96         
 18262  15960  87%    0.09K    397       46      1588K anon_vma               
 14548  12905  88%    1.00K    459       32     14688K kmalloc-1k             
 14162  14162 100%    0.05K    194       73       776K file_lock_ctx          
 13104  12141  92%    0.09K    312       42      1248K kmalloc-96             
 13062  13062 100%    0.19K    311       42      2488K cred_jar               
 13056  10983  84%    0.12K    408       32      1632K kmalloc-128            
 12192   8922  73%    0.66K    508       24      8128K proc_inode_cache       
 11730  11444  97%    0.69K   1444       46     46208K squashfs_inode_cache   
 11067  11067 100%    0.08K    217       51       868K task_delay_info        
 10752  10752 100%    0.03K     84      128       336K kmemleak_scan_area     
 10656   8666  81%    0.25K    333       32      2664K filp                   
 10252  10252 100%    0.18K    235       44      1880K kvm_mmu_page_header    
 10200  10200 100%    0.05K    120       85       480K ftrace_event_field     
 10176  10176 100%    0.12K    318       32      1272K pid                    
  9906   9906 100%    0.10K    254       39      1016K Acpi-ParseExt          
  9600   9213  95%    0.12K    300       32      1200K kmalloc-rcl-128        
  9520   9520 100%    0.07K    170       56       680K Acpi-Operand           
  8502   8063  94%    0.81K    218       39      6976K sock_inode_cache       
  7733   7733 100%    0.70K    169       46      5408K shmem_inode_cache      
  7392   7231  97%    0.19K    176       42      1408K skbuff_ext_cache       
  6552   6552 100%    0.19K    163       42      1304K kmalloc-rcl-192        
  6480   6480 100%    0.11K    180       36       720K khugepaged_mm_slot     
  6144   6144 100%    0.02K     24      256        96K ep_head                
  5439   5439 100%    0.42K    147       37      2352K btrfs_ordered_extent   
  5248   4981  94%    0.25K    164       32      1312K skbuff_head_cache      
  4792   4117  85%    4.00K    606        8     19392K biovec-max             
  4326   4326 100%    0.19K    103       42       824K proc_dir_entry         
  4125   4125 100%    0.24K    125       33      1000K tw_sock_TCPv6          
  3978   3978 100%    0.10K    102       39       408K buffer_head            
  3975   3769  94%    0.31K    159       25      1272K mnt_cache              
  3328   3200  96%    1.00K    104       32      3328K RAW                    
  3136   3136 100%    1.12K    112       28      3584K signal_cache           
  3072   2560  83%    0.03K     24      128        96K dnotify_struct         
  2910   2820  96%    1.06K     97       30      3104K UNIX                   
  2522   2396  95%    1.19K     97       26      3104K RAWv6                  
  2448   2448 100%    0.04K     24      102        96K pde_opener             
  2400   2400 100%    0.50K     75       32      1200K skbuff_fclone_cache    
  2112   2080  98%    1.00K     66       32      2112K biovec-64              
  1695   1587  93%    2.06K    113       15      3616K sighand_cache          
  1518   1518 100%    0.69K     33       46      1056K files_cache            
  1500   1500 100%    0.31K     60       25       480K nf_conntrack           
  1260    894  70%    6.06K    252        5      8064K task_struct            
  1260   1260 100%    1.06K     42       30      1344K mm_struct              
  1222   1158  94%    2.38K     94       13      3008K TCPv6                  
  1150   1150 100%    0.34K     25       46       400K taskstats              
   924    924 100%    0.56K     33       28       528K task_group             
   888    888 100%    0.21K     24       37       192K file_lock_cache        
   864    864 100%    0.11K     24       36        96K btrfs_trans_handle     
   855    855 100%    2.19K     62       14      1984K TCP                    
   851    851 100%    0.42K     23       37       368K uts_namespace          
   816    816 100%    0.12K     24       34        96K seq_file               
   816    816 100%    0.04K      8      102        32K ext4_extent_status     
   792    792 100%    0.24K     24       33       192K tw_sock_TCP            
   782    782 100%    0.94K     23       34       736K mqueue_inode_cache     
   720    720 100%    0.13K     24       30        96K pid_namespace          
   704    704 100%    0.06K     11       64        44K kmem_cache_node        
   648    648 100%    1.16K     24       27       768K perf_event             
   640    640 100%    0.12K     20       32        80K scsi_sense_cache       
   624    624 100%    0.30K     24       26       192K request_sock_TCP       
   624    624 100%    0.15K     24       26        96K fuse_request           
   596    566  94%    8.00K    149        4      4768K kmalloc-8k             
   576    576 100%    1.31K     24       24       768K UDPv6                  
   494    494 100%    0.30K     19       26       152K request_sock_TCPv6     
   480    480 100%    0.53K     16       30       256K user_namespace         
   432    432 100%    1.15K     16       27       512K ext4_inode_cache       
   416    416 100%    0.25K     13       32       104K kmem_cache             
   416    416 100%    0.61K     16       26       256K hugetlbfs_inode_cache  
   390    390 100%    0.81K     10       39       320K fuse_inode             
   306    306 100%    0.04K      3      102        12K bio_crypt_ctx          
   292    292 100%    0.05K      4       73        16K mbcache                
   260    260 100%    1.56K     13       20       416K bdev_cache             
   256    256 100%    0.02K      1      256         4K jbd2_revoke_table_s    
   232    232 100%    4.00K     29        8       928K names_cache            
   192    192 100%    1.98K     12       16       384K request_queue          
   170    170 100%    0.02K      1      170         4K mod_hash_entries       
   168    168 100%    4.12K     24        7       768K net_namespace          
   155    155 100%    0.26K      5       31        40K numa_policy            
   132    132 100%    0.72K      3       44        96K fat_inode_cache        
   128    128 100%    0.25K      4       32        32K dquot                  
   128    128 100%    0.06K      2       64         8K ext4_io_end            
   108    108 100%    2.61K      9       12       288K x86_emulator           
    84     84 100%    0.19K      2       42        16K ext4_groupinfo_4k      
    68     68 100%    0.12K      2       34         8K jbd2_journal_head      
    68     68 100%    0.12K      2       34         8K abd_t                  
    64     64 100%    8.00K     16        4       512K irq_remap_cache        
    64     64 100%    2.00K      4       16       128K biovec-128             
    63     63 100%    4.06K      9        7       288K x86_fpu                
    56     56 100%    0.07K      1       56         4K fsnotify_mark          
    56     56 100%    0.14K      2       28         8K ext4_allocation_context
    42     42 100%    0.75K      1       42        32K dax_cache              
    40     40 100%    0.20K      1       40         8K ip4-frags              
    36     36 100%    7.86K      9        4       288K kvm_vcpu               
    30     30 100%    1.06K      1       30        32K dmaengine-unmap-128    
    24     24 100%    0.66K      1       24        16K ovl_inode              
    15     15 100%    2.06K      1       15        32K dmaengine-unmap-256    
     6      6 100%   16.00K      3        2        96K zio_buf_comb_16384     
     0      0   0%    0.01K      0      512         0K kmalloc-rcl-8          
     0      0   0%    0.02K      0      256         0K kmalloc-rcl-16         
     0      0   0%    0.03K      0      128         0K kmalloc-rcl-32         
     0      0   0%    0.25K      0       32         0K kmalloc-rcl-256        
     0      0   0%    0.50K      0       32         0K kmalloc-rcl-512        
     0      0   0%    1.00K      0       32         0K kmalloc-rcl-1k         
     0      0   0%    2.00K      0       16         0K kmalloc-rcl-2k         
     0      0   0%    4.00K      0        8         0K kmalloc-rcl-4k         
     0      0   0%    8.00K      0        4         0K kmalloc-rcl-8k         
     0      0   0%    0.09K      0       42         0K dma-kmalloc-96         
     0      0   0%    0.19K      0       42         0K dma-kmalloc-192        
     0      0   0%    0.01K      0      512         0K dma-kmalloc-8          
     0      0   0%    0.02K      0      256         0K dma-kmalloc-16         
     0      0   0%    0.03K      0      128         0K dma-kmalloc-32         
     0      0   0%    0.06K      0       64         0K dma-kmalloc-64         
     0      0   0%    0.12K      0       32         0K dma-kmalloc-128        
     0      0   0%    0.25K      0       32         0K dma-kmalloc-256        
     0      0   0%    0.50K      0       32         0K dma-kmalloc-512        
     0      0   0%    1.00K      0       32         0K dma-kmalloc-1k         
     0      0   0%    2.00K      0       16         0K dma-kmalloc-2k         
     0      0   0%    4.00K      0        8         0K dma-kmalloc-4k         
     0      0   0%    8.00K      0        4         0K dma-kmalloc-8k         
     0      0   0%    0.12K      0       34         0K iint_cache             
     0      0   0%    1.00K      0       32         0K PING                   
     0      0   0%    0.75K      0       42         0K xfrm_state             
     0      0   0%    0.37K      0       43         0K request_sock_subflow   
     0      0   0%    1.81K      0       17         0K MPTCP                  
     0      0   0%    0.62K      0       25         0K dio                    
     0      0   0%    0.19K      0       42         0K userfaultfd_ctx_cache  
     0      0   0%    0.03K      0      128         0K ext4_pending_reservation
     0      0   0%    0.08K      0       51         0K ext4_fc_dentry_update  
     0      0   0%    0.04K      0      102         0K fat_cache              
     0      0   0%    0.81K      0       39         0K ecryptfs_auth_tok_list_item
     0      0   0%    0.02K      0      256         0K ecryptfs_file_cache    
     0      0   0%    0.94K      0       34         0K ecryptfs_inode_cache   
     0      0   0%    2.82K      0       11         0K dm_uevent              
     0      0   0%    3.23K      0        9         0K kcopyd_job             
     0      0   0%    1.19K      0       26         0K PINGv6                 
     0      0   0%    0.18K      0       44         0K ip6-frags              
     0      0   0%    2.00K      0       16         0K MPTCPv6                
     0      0   0%    0.13K      0       30         0K fscrypt_info           
     0      0   0%    0.25K      0       32         0K fsverity_info          
     0      0   0%    1.25K      0       25         0K AF_VSOCK               
     0      0   0%    0.19K      0       42         0K kcf_sreq_cache         
     0      0   0%    0.50K      0       32         0K kcf_areq_cache         
     0      0   0%    0.19K      0       42         0K kcf_context_cache      
     0      0   0%    4.00K      0        8         0K zfs_btree_leaf_cache   
     0      0   0%    0.44K      0       36         0K ddt_entry_cache        
     0      0   0%    1.22K      0       26         0K zio_cache              
     0      0   0%    0.05K      0       85         0K zio_link_cache         
     0      0   0%    0.50K      0       32         0K zio_buf_comb_512       
     0      0   0%    1.00K      0       32         0K zio_buf_comb_1024      
     0      0   0%    1.50K      0       21         0K zio_buf_comb_1536      
     0      0   0%    2.00K      0       16         0K zio_buf_comb_2048      
     0      0   0%    2.50K      0       12         0K zio_buf_comb_2560      
     0      0   0%    3.00K      0       10         0K zio_buf_comb_3072      
     0      0   0%    3.50K      0        9         0K zio_buf_comb_3584      
     0      0   0%    4.00K      0        8         0K zio_buf_comb_4096      
     0      0   0%    8.00K      0        4         0K zio_buf_comb_5120      
     0      0   0%    8.00K      0        4         0K zio_buf_comb_6144      
     0      0   0%    8.00K      0        4         0K zio_buf_comb_7168      
     0      0   0%    8.00K      0        4         0K zio_buf_comb_8192      
     0      0   0%   12.00K      0        2         0K zio_buf_comb_10240     
     0      0   0%   12.00K      0        2         0K zio_buf_comb_12288     
     0      0   0%   16.00K      0        2         0K zio_buf_comb_14336     
     0      0   0%   16.00K      0        2         0K lz4_cache              
     0      0   0%    0.24K      0       33         0K sa_cache               
     0      0   0%    0.96K      0       33         0K dnode_t                
     0      0   0%    0.32K      0       24         0K arc_buf_hdr_t_full     
     0      0   0%    0.38K      0       41         0K arc_buf_hdr_t_full_crypt
     0      0   0%    0.09K      0       42         0K arc_buf_hdr_t_l2only   
     0      0   0%    0.08K      0       51         0K arc_buf_t              
     0      0   0%    0.38K      0       42         0K dmu_buf_impl_t         
     0      0   0%    0.37K      0       43         0K zil_lwb_cache          
     0      0   0%    0.15K      0       26         0K zil_zcw_cache          
     0      0   0%    0.13K      0       30         0K sio_cache_0            
     0      0   0%    0.15K      0       26         0K sio_cache_1            
     0      0   0%    0.16K      0       24         0K sio_cache_2            
     0      0   0%    1.06K      0       30         0K zfs_znode_cache        
     0      0   0%    0.09K      0       46         0K zfs_znode_hold_cache
```

Comment: What do you see with `cat /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak`? And before you enabled `kmemleak` with your kernel, what showed up as the top slab?

Comment: @aviro please look at my update

Comment: You should [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/717838/edit) your original question with the information in the answer. You should never use answers to provide additional details. In addition, in your original answer you showed the content of `/proc/meminfo` after you enabled `memleak`, and there we saw that that Slab was taking most of the memory, and the top hitter in slab was `kmemleak_object`. I would like to see the content of `/proc/meminfo` without enabling `memleak`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it was a problem with the nct6775 driver.
It was loaded by the /etc/modules file.
After removing it the error disappeared.